# Cocoa NSScrollView starts at center

Tags: cocoa

I have a NSScrollView item in my main window. Whenever I launch the program, there is text in the scroll view and it starts at the center. Shouldn't the user start reading at the top but why does the app launch it at the center? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you do not set your views up correctly.
Here's the information I have:
1: You use Interface Builder to set up your views.
2: You are using a NSTextView
3: The code you use for changing the text is:
   [[_chapterContent insertText:[Book objectForKey:bookAndChapters]];
4: As you're using a NSTextView, we're not dealing with an issue caused by flipped coordinates.

I'm not sure whether you should use insertText for this task.
At least, you can use something like this...

```
range.location = 0;
range.length = 0;
[textView setSelectedRange:range];
```

...to set the position of the caret.

You can then do a...

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
```

...if you like.

Note: You can use setSelectedRange with a length of 0 and any location within [textStorage length], to position the caret.

-Let me know if this makes the change you need.

I'd suggest using...

```
textStorage = [textView textStorage];
range.location = 0;
range.length = [textStorage length];
if([self shouldChangeTextInRange:range replacementString:string])
{
    [textStorage beginEditing];
    [textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:range withAttributedString:attrStr];
    [textStorage endEditing];        
}
```

... to replace the text with an attributed string.
If you don't need an attributed string, there's a simpler method available:

```
    [textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:str];
```

It's worked well for me (and a number of other people) for many years; it's the recommended way of changing the contents of the NSTextView.
-If you just want to replace the entire contents with a string, you can use

```
[textView setString:string];
```

Comment: 1) I set it ups in Interface builder 2)Yes, NSTextView 3) [_chapterContent insertText:[Book objectForKey:bookAndChapters]]; 4) The setFlipped doesn't work. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Good information. Have you checked your positioning flags for both the NSScrollView and the NSTextView (which is inside the NSScrollView) ? -The NSTextView should be fixed to all sides of the NSScrollView, and it should be flexible horizontally and vertically.

Comment: I found out that I used InsertString instead of setString